# Row span in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

```
<tr class="ng-table-team" data-card="card-{{cardIndex}}">
 <td data-label="{{data.fields.label}}" ng-repeat="field in data.fields" ng-show="key != 'attributes'" ng-if="obj.isTrue" rowspan = {{obj.count}}>
    <div class="slds-truncate" ng-if="data.fields[$index].label === 'Name'" data-label="{{data.fields[$index].label}}">    
        <span>{{obj.Name}}</span></br><span> {{obj.Email}}</span>
    </div>
   <div  ng-if="data.fields[$index].label != 'Name'" data-label="{{data.fields[$index].label}}"> 
   {{obj | getter: data.fields[$index] | picker: data.fields[$index].type}}
    </div>
</td>
<td data-label="{{data.fields.label}}" ng-repeat="field in data.fields" ng-show="key != 'attributes'" ng-if="!obj.isTrue">
    <div class="slds-truncate" ng-if="data.fields[$index].label === 'Name'" data-label="{{data.fields[$index].label}}">    
        <span>{{obj.Name}}</span></br><span> {{obj.Email}}</span>
    </div>
   <div  ng-if="data.fields[$index].label != 'Name'" data-label="{{data.fields[$index].label}}"> 
   {{obj | getter: data.fields[$index] | picker: data.fields[$index].type}}
    </div>
</td>
```

I am new to Angular JS and trying to apply rowspan here based on my scenario. Can anyone help here as to what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: what is the error?